# How can I write to the setup file from Navigate - Open Setup?

Tags: eclipse

The new Eclipse, I don't know from which version, has in Navigate menu the access to different, local and global setups.

Navigate - Open Setup - *choose local/global/user setup*

Even [recent Eclipse documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/index.jsp) has not a word about that feature. And when I open any property by Text Editor or somehow else, it is not editable.

How can I edit the Eclipse setups using the special feature, obviously introduced for that aim?

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring

Comment: Thank you, I have found that, too, but I still did not found how to edit the setups. So, that can be a start for the answer, but it is not the whole answer yet.

Comment: I think these setups are read only and you have to [create your own setup](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring#Creating_a_Setup_Project_Model) and then [test it](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring#Testing_the_Setup_Model). What exactly are you want to do? The [recent Eclipse documentation contains a separate book here](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.oomph.setup.doc/html/Overview.html) (which is also included in the application). There are also videos about Oomph authoring on YouTube.

Answer (score 2):

You can add items to `Workspace` setup by opening it, then right click on Workspace and select an item to add

[image]

Same option could be available when you open a resource in editor. Not all the items offer the `New Child` option.

[image]

On closing the setup, it will ask to save it.

Comment: I cannot say that is exactly what I wanted. It is only half of the task. If we could simultaneously *delete* an item - that would be enough to substitute *edit* operation.... Anyway, +1, and thank you.

Comment: It's a whole feature full of stuff to explore. I'm trying to find how to clone existing configurations. Will update the answer as I find new things.

Comment: Yes, it is very interesting. But all manuals that I found were misty. Do you know any good pages?

Comment: The book mentioned by @howler looks good. Will try to add more to the answer later today.