# What is the best way to manage project preference

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

A very general question: I have a set of plugins that create my own Eclipse project, with a reference to the IProject interface. I need to manage some preference at workspace level (scope), and some of these need an "override" at project scope.
So if I set *use project settings* the code should use the project scoped preference and not the workspace scoped ones.
So the question is: is there any best way to manage this case, any pattern or something?

I have seen already:

- https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mutatis-mutandis/overlay-pages.html  which is really my case!
- https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_preferences.htm
- https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html

Comment: Seems you need Eclipse OOMPH Authoring. [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56045056/2834978) something about that.

Comment: Ok I see.. but it seem really complicate, mainly because of the lack of documentation. Do you know any book that explain the framework from the basics?

Comment: Seems the ones mentioned on the link above are the best you can get in terms of 'book', there's some pages on the web about that though. Not a really popular technology but still powerful. A good starting point seems to install eclipse and do the setup while recording everything with oomph. Trying to get it from an existing installation is not really convenient as starting point.

Comment: But here I am talking about the project preference, that I need to save for every project, preferably **INTO** the project folder. 
In the meantime I have found the project scoped properties, 
https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_preferences.htm
which seems to be best solutions.. <br>
This saves the preference in a `.setting` subfolder in the project folder.